# question about probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

[image]

How is the last column calculated? I don't understand, and I don't understand the explanation. $P(A \cap B)$ is calculated by $P(A)P(B\mid A),$ right? How is $P(A\mid B)$ calculated? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Bayes theorem,

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}.$$

Please note that

$$P(B) = \sum_{j=1}^6 P(B|A_j) P(A_j),$$

where $A_j$ is the event that the die came up $j$.

Comment: Thanks +1, can you expand the last part please?

Comment: Yes, note that $P(B)=P(B \cap 1)+P(B\cap 2)+P(B\cap 3)+P(B\cap 4)+P(B\cap 5) + P(B\cap 6)$.  Then use $P(B\cap 1)=P(B|1)P(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $P (A|B)$ is called Probability of event $A$ given event $B$. Consider if $A=3$. The probability of $A=3$ is $\frac 16$. The probability of $B$ given $A$ is $\frac 12$ and the probability of $A\cap B$, or usually we call the joint probability of $A$ and $B$ or the probability of $A$ and $B$ happening is $\frac 1{12}$. Using [Baye's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), we can easily see that 
\begin{align}
\text{Pr } (B|A) &= \frac{\text{Pr }(A\cap B)}{\text{Pr } (A)}\\
\frac12 &= \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac 16}
\end{align}